# How to deploy tutorial project on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am completely new to GAE and maybe this question could be quite trivial, anyway I present my case.

I followed the "Try Google App Engine Now" tutorial without any problems (I choose the java project and I use Chrome).
When I try to deploy the project on GAE something goes wrong, I can create the project on GAE but I don't know what to do next:

[image]

What command should I use to deploy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have been able to create your application and have been successful in running it locally, please follow the instructions over here for uploading your application.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Uploading_the_App

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should do some configuration such as filling the project-ID at app.yaml. 
Then you can use the terminal to change to your project directory, afterwards you can invoke Maven as 'mvn appengine:update'

You can follow the instructions at the following link:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading